# Jetpack Compose - Variable Scope / Best Practice

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Android Native coding (Kotlin / Jetpack Compose) with a long background in AS3 Mobile App coding (OOP). I like to follow the same path and break Composable codes into smaller chunks, OOP, to make it easy to maintain.

For instance, this is the MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {          
            MakeNav()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MakeNav() {
    var navCon = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navCon, startDestination = "home") {
        composable("home") {
            MakeHome(navCon)
        }

        composable("list") {
            MakeList()
        }
    }
}
```

And to compose the HomePage:

```
@Composable
fun MakeHome(navCon: NavController){
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ){
        Column() {
            MakeHomeHdr()
            MakeHomeBdy()
            MakeHomeFtr(navCon)
        }
    }
}
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe97S.jpg)

**Question**:

- Can I / Should I assign variables in the Mother Composable (i.e **MakeHome**) and then access those from the Sub-Composables?

For instance, in the **MakeHomeBdy()** I have 3 Variables which I need to pass to NavHost later:

```
    var txtSub by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Call Mr. X")}
    var txtDte by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("1400/05/21")}
    var txtTme by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("10:01")}

    Column (
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(30.dp)
    ){
        TextField(
            value = txtSub,
            onValueChange = { txtSub = it },
            placeholder = { Text("some text") },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
...
```

When the Button in **MakeHomeFtr()** is clicked, I need to pass Data:

```
@Composable
fun MakeHomeFtr(navCon: NavController){
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = {navCon.navigate("list")},
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(30.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
        }
    }

}
```

In this example, I have no access to the Variables in **MakeHomeBdy()** to pass them to the NavHost:

```
NavHost(startDestination = "home") {
    ...
    composable("list/{txtSub}/{txtDte}/{txtTme}") {...}
}
```

Where should I assign those Vars? What is the "Best" practice to build the code neat and clean, from beginning.

There are workarounds such as saving all Variables inside a Data Class, and access those from anywhere, which I don't think is correct. So what is the best way please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found my own answer, that is, I can not think Old style and use New tools. This means rather than thinking OOP, I need to switch my mind to MVVM and follow the guidelines of Google:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide